# Upgrading to PHP 7.1 Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in .../themeXX/includes/includes.php on line 76

Tags: php, joomla

*Before someone tags as "already replied"* : I have tried most of the previous posts on the same subject but doesn't work. I have set numeric values and {is_numeric} but I must be doing something wrong or is it something else?

```
//Get main content width

//Get Left column grid width
    if($this->countModules('aside-left') && $hideByOption == false && $view !== 'form'){ 
        $asideLeftWidth = $this->params->get('asideLeftWidth');
    } else {
        $asideLeftWidth = "";
    }

//Get Right column grid width
    if($this->countModules('aside-right') && $hideByOption == false &&     $view !== 'form'){ 
        $asideRightWidth = $this->params->get('asideRightWidth');
    } else {
        $asideRightWidth = "";
    }
```

Line 76 below

```
        $mainContentWidth = 12 - ($asideLeftWidth + $asideRightWidth);
```

Comment: So what does `asideLeftWidth` and `$asideRightWidth` contain? Try echoing/var_dumping the values before that line. You might also want to try assigning 0 instead of an empty string `""`

Comment: They are module positions. From template.css :
`#aside-right .moduletable {
  margin-bottom: 39px;
}
#aside-left .moduletable {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}`
As for assigning 0, I have tried already, no luck...

Comment: If the variables contain those exact words, then you can't do 12 - #aside-right..... But if it contains a number, then math should work.

Comment: @aynber You were correct. I was doing a stupid mistake (lack of sleep). Filling the string `""` with 0, fixed the problem! Thanks